# Global loops spin counter

Tags: php, loops

Is there a way to count, how many spins loops has a PHP file and the files included in it?

I write simple framework and want to keep statistics of rotations made of loops.

```
include "fiveLoops.php"; // 250 spins 
 while(true){
    break;
    // 1 spin;
 }
 for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    // 10 spins; 
 }     
 // total spins 261
```

Is there has a feature built into the language to give me such information.

Comment: imho there is no buildin function ...so it would be hard to count loops

Comment: think you don't want that ... you'll have to set a global counter (e.g. $_SESSION['spin_counts] = 0 and in every "loop" increase the counter

Comment: I do not want to be with sessions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function in PHP yet to keep statistics of rotations made of loops. Hence, you need to use a counter that will be stored in the file that includes your function.

To store that variable and include that variable in a different PHP page, your function page, you would want to use a `session variable`. By default, a session variable stores your variable on the server, not on the clients cookies for around one hour.

You could for instance have `$_SESSION['COUNT']` and initiate it to zero in the file that the loop will occur.

When working with session it is important to start the session using `session_start` and you would put that at the top of every file using session.

On the function page, you would want to retrieve the session variable and increment it accordingly inside your `while loop`.

Comment: I do not want to be with sessions. Is there another varyant? Redefining constants or something elsе?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with working with session, you could also use ajax to dynamically post the variable information inside the function file, but I think using sessions is an easy way

Comment: I have a file that is included in the other. I do not want to use sessions. I use OOP, tokens statistics and other information. Please give me other ideas.